# Line numbers relative to the screen

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, line-numbers

Is it possible to make Vim show line numbers relative to the screen? Not to the beginning of the file, and not to the current position of the cursor, but relative to the first line that is currently being displayed? So that `12G`, `40G`, etc. could be used as a more fine-grained alternative to `H`, `M`, and `L`?

Answer (score 3):

Not without patching the source (source: the only relevant options are `number` and `relativenumber`).

I do recall some recent questions about using signs to create custom numbers. If anyone has those links, feel free to add them here.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not going to try and patch Vim, but if anyone has those links, I'd be interested.